# ASP MVC Core architecture for multiple client SAP integrations

Tags: c#, rest, architecture, asp.net-core-mvc

A little bit of context: We currently have a monolith application with an .NET ASP NET MVC Core architecture using CQRS & EF Core to 1 big SQL database. This cloud solution can be accessed by numerous customers all having exactly the same implementation. Certain parts of the application can be configured so that not all customers are affected by new changes, but it's nothing more than configuring in the database and then hiding/disabling sections of the application.

What we're looking for: for some of these customers we need to provide SAP interfacing ( data import & export ) API's, but as we know from experience these interfacings almost always differ for each customer. As an example: an order or delivery coming from SAP can be the same for all customers but it could be that customer X has a custom implementation and thus requires a custom implementation on our side as well. The customers need to call API's that we develop for them and we'll need to call API's in their SAP systems. In Short: each customer API needs to be developed seperately but we would also like to have a base set of API's that can be used for a customer without customizing it.

What would be a good way to set this up? Preferably we can deploy each set of customer API's as seperately so we don't impact the other customers.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You likely want a connector pattern, where you have a core API (vanilla) which you can put connectors on that talk to the customized APIs.  The default one can be a straight pass-through but you can deploy connectors for as many customers as you need.  It also gives you a point to include credentials, endpoints, etc (in the connector).

If nothing else, differing customers will have differing versions of SAP, and you will need different connectors to up/downgrade the API calls to the target instance.